# Localhost:8080 cannot connect (Shinyproxy at Wiindows)

Tags: r, shiny, shinyproxy

Following getting started at shinyproxy.io I installed shinyproxy at windows 11

1. docker: pulled the image: “docker pull openanalytics/shinyproxy-demo”
2. installed java v.15
3. downloaded shinyproxy-2.6.1.jar
4. Inserted hosts in deamon.json (located in .docker under users)
5. i started shinyproxy: java -jar shinyproxy-2.6.1.jar
6. I opened localhost:8080 in Chrome and got the message: Cannot connect

Logs:

```
PS C:\7.20 Shiiny proxy java> java -jar shinyproxy-2.6.1.jar

    . ____ _ __ _ _*
    /\ / ’ __ _ () __ __ _ \ \ \ *
    *( ( )__ | '_ | '| | ’ / _` | \ \ \ *
    \/ _)| |)| | | | | || (| | ) ) ) )*
    ’ || .__|| ||| |__, | / / / /*
    =========||==============|/=///_/*
    :: Spring Boot :: (v2.5.12)*
    2022-05-24 07:17:14.262 INFO 12580 — [ main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
    2022-05-24 07:17:14.272 INFO 12580 — [ main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Redis repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-05-24 07:17:14.352 INFO 12580 — [ main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 47 ms. Found 0 Redis repository interfaces.
2022-05-24 07:17:15.234 INFO 12580 — [ main] e.o.c.service.IdentifierService : ShinyProxy runtimeId: 13976d5c-4ad0-426e-ada0-d9e457cf10ef
2022-05-24 07:17:15.244 INFO 12580 — [ main] e.o.c.service.IdentifierService : ShinyProxy instanceID (hash of config): unknown-instance-id
2022-05-24 07:17:16.021 WARN 12580 — [ main] io.undertow.websockets.jsr : UT026010: Buffer pool was not set on WebSocketDeploymentInfo, the default pool will be used
2022-05-24 07:17:16.079 INFO 12580 — [ main] io.undertow.servlet : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-05-24 07:17:16.080 INFO 12580 — [ main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3340 ms
2022-05-24 07:17:16.277 INFO 12580 — [ main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean : Filter orderedFormContentFilter was not registered (disabled)
2022-05-24 07:17:16.647 INFO 12580 — [ main] s.s.l.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource : URL ‘ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389/dc=example,dc=com’, root DN is ‘dc=example,dc=com’
2022-05-24 07:17:16.670 INFO 12580 — [ main] .s.s.l.u.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator : groupSearchBase is empty. Searches will be performed from the context source base
2022-05-24 07:17:16.794 INFO 12580 — [ main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Will not secure any request
2022-05-24 07:17:16.818 INFO 12580 — [ main] e.o.c.stat.StatCollectorFactory : Disabled. Usage statistics will not be processed.
2022-05-24 07:17:16.836 WARN 12580 — [ main] org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode : [THYMELEAF][main] Template Mode ‘HTML5’ is deprecated. Using Template Mode ‘HTML’ instead.
2022-05-24 07:17:17.447 INFO 12580 — [ main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping : Adding welcome page template: index
2022-05-24 07:17:17.834 INFO 12580 — [ main] o.s.l.c.support.AbstractContextSource : Property ‘userDn’ not set - anonymous context will be used for read-write operations
2022-05-24 07:17:18.090 INFO 12580 — [ main] io.undertow : starting server: Undertow - 2.2.8.Final
2022-05-24 07:17:18.112 INFO 12580 — [ main] org.xnio : XNIO version 3.8.4.Final
2022-05-24 07:17:18.135 INFO 12580 — [ main] org.xnio.nio : XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.4.Final
2022-05-24 07:17:18.282 INFO 12580 — [ main] org.jboss.threads : JBoss Threads version 3.1.0.Final
2022-05-24 07:17:18.376 INFO 12580 — [ main] o.s.b.w.e.undertow.UndertowWebServer : Undertow started on port(s) 8080 (http)
2022-05-24 07:17:18.501 INFO 12580 — [ main] io.undertow.servlet : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-05-24 07:17:18.502 INFO 12580 — [ main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 119 ms
2022-05-24 07:17:18.526 INFO 12580 — [ main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver : Exposing 1 endpoint(s) beneath base path ‘/actuator’
2022-05-24 07:17:18.619 INFO 12580 — [ main] io.undertow : starting server: Undertow - 2.2.8.Final
2022-05-24 07:17:18.641 INFO 12580 — [ main] o.s.b.w.e.undertow.UndertowWebServer : Undertow started on port(s) 9090 (http)
2022-05-24 07:17:18.679 INFO 12580 — [ main] e.o.c.service.AppRecoveryService : Recovery of running apps disabled
2022-05-24 07:17:18.680 INFO 12580 — [ main] e.o.c.util.StartupEventListener : Started ShinyProxy 2.6.1 (ContainerProxy 0.8.11)
2022-05-24 07:17:45.587 INFO 12580 — [ XNIO-1 task-1] io.undertow.servlet : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet ‘dispatcherServlet’
2022-05-24 07:17:45.588 INFO 12580 — [ XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Initializing Servlet ‘dispatcherServlet’
2022-05-24 07:17:45.591 INFO 12580 — [ XNIO-1 task-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Completed initialization in 3 ms
2022-05-24 07:17:45.662 ERROR 12580 — [ XNIO-1 task-3] io.undertow.request : UT005023: Exception handling request to /

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xnio.channels.Channels

   at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:619) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]*
   at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:497) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]*
   at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:586) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]*
   at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:211) ~[undertow-servlet-2.2.8.Final.jar!/:2.2.8.Final]*
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:130) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar!/:4.0.4]*
   at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse.sendRedirect(FirewalledResponse.java:48) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.5.jar!/:5.5.5]*
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:130) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar!/:4.0.4]*
   at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:136) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.5.jar!/:5.5.5]*
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:130) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar!/:4.0.4]*
   at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:136) ~[spring-security-web-5.5.5.jar!/:5.5.5]*
   at org.springframework.se*
```

I SEE THE ERROR
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xnio.channels.Channels

Please help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem try adding this:

```
-Djdk.io.File.enableADS=true
```

I bet the problem you've faced is similar to https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8285445

So you can either use *jdk.io.File.enableADS=true* or downgrade your JDK or download version where fix is applied :)